# How to grab the number after a specific word in a string in php

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a huge string that I need to search for the word "Error" which will then have a space and a number after it.  So in the string it would look like "Error 2".  I need to grab that number after the error and output it.  How would I go about doing that in php.  I'm assuming you use some type of regex, but I am not very experienced with it.  Thanks!

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, bring it to us to help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.  Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: Use `str_pos`, much faster than RegExp.

Comment: There are some very handy web apps that can help you gain experience with RegEx. Here are just two: http://regexpal.com/ and http://refiddle.com/

Answer (score 3):

Use capturing group:

```
$huge_string = "looooong string Error 22, another looooooong string.";
preg_match("/Error (\d+)/", $huge_string, $match);
var_dump($match[1]);
```

prints

```
22
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_match`

```
preg_match("/Error (\d+) /",$string,$matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

$matches[1] will store the first matching parenthetical string `(\d+)`

For full usage look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php